# Активная и неактивная кнопка по результатам sql-запроса

Tags: php, javascript, sql

При нажатии на одну из дату календаря формируется дата и бд проверяется, есть ли у этой даты свободное время, если нет — то блокируем все кнопки, если некоторое время занято, то блокируем эти кнопки. И если на эту дату ни одно время не занято, то все кнопки активны.

```js
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay: 1,
        height: 200,

        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'οюнь', 'οюль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв.', 'Фев.', 'Март', 'Апр.', 'Май', 'οюнь', 'οюль', 'Авг.', 'Сент.', 'Окт.', 'Ноя.', 'Дек.'],
        dayNames: ["Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"],
        dayNamesShort: ["ВС", "ПН", "ВТ", "СР", "ЧТ", "ПТ", "СБ"],
        buttonText: {
          prev: "&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;",
          next: "&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;",
          prevYear: "&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;",
          nextYear: "&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;",
          today: "Сегодня",
          month: "Месяц",
          week: "Неделя",
          day: "День",
          add: "Добавить"
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,

        select: function(start) {
          $(".fc-cell-overlay").click(function() {

            var btn = document.getElementById('ds').disabled = true;

            $.ajax({
              url: 'test.php',
              data: 'postVar=' + start.format("yyyy-mm-dd"),


              type: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                $("#info").text(data);
                $("#btn-click:hidden").slideDown("slow");

                $(".btn-sample").click(function() {
                  var text = $(this).text();

                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'chekTime.php',
                    data: 'time=' + text + '&postVar=' + start.format("yyyy-mm-dd"),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data) {
                      $("#info").text(data);
                      if (data.value == "время занят") {

                      }

                    }

                  });
                });

              },
              error: function() {
                alert("No PHP script: ");
              }
            });




            return false;
          });


          calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: [

        ]
      });
    });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Попапы</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my_scripts.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='js/fullcalendar.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='js/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/func.js"></script>
  <script src="date.format.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="link_group">
    <a class="show_popup" rel="tabs_info" href="#">Окно со вкладками</a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup tabs_info">
    <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
    <h2>Вкладки (tabs)</h2>
    <div class="selectTabs">
      <span id="info"></span>
      <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab1">
          <div id="calendar"></div>
          <span style="display:none;" id="info"></span>
          <span style="display:none;" id="add"></span>
          <span id="time"><ul id="list-timer" class="list-no-act">
               <section class="color-7" id="btn-click"style="display:none;">
        
                <p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >09:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >09:30:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >10:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >10:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >11:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >11:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >12:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >12:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >13:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >13:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >14:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >14:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >15:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >15:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >16:00</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >16:30</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn-sample" id="time-is-18" onclick="" >17:00</button>
                </p>
                
            </section>
</span>
          <style type="text/css">
            #calendar {
              width: 785px;
              margin-top: -190px;
              opacity: 0.7;
              background: white;
              /* Цвет фона */
              padding: 5px;
              /* Поля вокруг текста */
              body {
                margin-top: 40px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
              }
              #calendar {
                width: 900px;
                margin: 0 auto;
              }
          </style>
          </style>
          <div id="box" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок</div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
    <?php
include('bd.php');
    // Если запрос идёт не из Ajax
/*    if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != "XMLHttpRequest" )
    {
        exit("Access denied!");
    }*/


$firstquarter = '09:00:00 , 09:30:00, 10:00:00, 10:30:00, 11:30:00, 12:00:00, 12:30:00, 13:00:00, 13:30:00, 14:00:00, 14:30:00, 15:00:00, 15:30:00, 16:00:00, 16:30:00, 17:00:00';
$arr = explode(",",$firstquarter);

$date = $_POST['postVar'];
/*$check= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `events`='$date' AND `Time`='$firstquarter'");*/
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `events`='$date' ");
//$sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE );AND `Time` IN (".implode(',',$arr).")

 if (mysql_num_rows($sql)>6)
 {
          echo "дата занята";
     exit();
 }
 else
 {
    echo 'дата свободная';
}

?>





<?php
include('bd.php');


$date = $_POST['postVar'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `events`='$date' AND `Time`='$time'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo 'время занято';
    exit();
} else {
    echo 'время свободен';
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: А что подсказать то. Структура таблицы точно не ясна. Вижу, в ней вроде время есть. Ну так и отдать из базы на клиента список занятых часов на этот день, в виде какого нибудь массива в json

Comment: @Mike, подозреваю, что вопрос в том - как заблокировать нужные кнопки в зависимости от ответа

Comment: @Grundy да именоо

Comment: @Сергей74rus, а вы, кстати, знаете, что используете несколько раз один и тот же id? `id="time-is-18"`? Это не хорошо и может приводить к неожиданным результатам при попытке выбрать элементы с таким id

Comment: Ну тогда например кнопкам id дать такие, что бы из времени легко получить нужные id. что то типа `time-is-17-00`, `time-is-17-30`. И время с сервера прямо в таком формате вернуть - через тире

Comment: @Mike вот я сформирвал                                                                       $ta = mysql_query("SELECT `Time` FROM `events`"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ta)){ // оформим каждую строку результата

    $data[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($data);    не пойму как мне его получить в  js и заблокировать занятые кнопки времени

Comment: Вы текст в вопросе правили. Ну теперь на клиенте var data=JSON.parse(data); Ну конечно кроме этого json туда ничего приходить не должно. И цикл по этому массиву с отключением кнопок, по их id видимо, если вы им дали такие id как я предложил